# yo code gives an error during installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, yo

I have `WIN10`:

> D:\dev\editor>node --version && npm --version
>   v10.15.3
>   6.4.1
>
> D:\dev\editor>yo --version
>   3.1.1

and

> D:\dev\editor>git --version
>   git version 2.16.2.windows.1

I try write:

```
D:\dev\editor>yo code                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮                                                                                                                                                                        
 |       |    │   Welcome to the Visual  │                                                                                                                                                                        
 |--(o)--|    │   Studio Code Extension  │                                                                                                                                                                       
 `---------´   │        generator!        │                                                                                                                                                                        
 ( _´U`_ )    ╰──────────────────────────╯                                                                                                                                                                        
 /___A___\   /                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  |  ~  |                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 __'.___.'__                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 events.js:180                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event                                                                                                                                                                            
 ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ([object Object])                                                                                                                                                      
 at module.exports.emit (events.js:178:17)                                                                                                                                                                        
 at module.exports.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)                                                                                                                                                           
 at Immediate.setImmediate (C:\Users\Aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator- 
 code\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:668:20)                                                               
 at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)                                                                                                                                                                                
 at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)                                                                                                                                                                              
 at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)                                                                                                                                                                            
 at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:120:23)
```

And I have error, what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your `node_modules` directory and reinstalling all of your packages with: `npm install`?...

Comment: I try, but i have empty directory for example:
`
D:\dev\editor>npm audit                                                                                                                                                                                          npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON                                                                                                                                                                                      npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json  
`

Comment: Sounds like you need `npm-init` to start a new project.

Comment: I do `npm-init`,  `npm install`  and I get two files: `package.json` and `package-lock.json` but I have error like as above